# TypeError in a simple method call

Tags: javascript

[RESOLVED]

defining the class

```
var Stone = function(args){

    var _this = this;
    inherit(_this, args); //just copy all attributes from args to _this

    _this.w = 32;
    _this.h = 32;
    _this.obstacle = true;
    _this.padding = 0;
    _this.sprite = {
        x: 32,
        y: 0
    };

    _this.draw = function(){
        console.log(_this);
        CanvasPainter.sprite("background", _this.sprite.x, _this.sprite.y,
                             _this.x, _this.y, _this.w, _this.h);
    };
};
```

defining the object

```
var stone = new Stone({
    x: 480,
    y: 320
});
```

invoking the method

```
stone.draw(); //throws "TypeError: Type error"
```

I already know that I am doing something stupid.  Can you help me find it?

Here is the stone object:

```
stone = {
  draw: function (),
  h: 32,
  obstacle: true,
  padding: 0,
  sprite: {x: 32, y: 0},
  w: 32,
  x: 480,
  y: 320
}
```

Actually the error comes from CanvasPainter.draw
was a stupid thing I`ve done

everything else is fine, thanks for help

Comment: Looks like the real problem is in CanvasPainter.sprite... Can you get a minimal runnable example of your error?

Comment: Can you provide the inherit method? Wouldn't hurt to check _this before and after being passed to the inherit method.

Comment: yeah, you are right, well, I am using it on other situations, let me check it out and will come back

Comment: I'm not sure which browser you're using, but in Chrome the message "Type error" occurs if you're drawing something on canvas that is not an image.

Comment: In your `stone` object, what do you expect `draw: function ()` to accomplish?  Are you trying to call a `function` whose name matches a keyword or are you trying to define a function object?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `inherit` function defined? The function executed fine for me. The only difference is instead of `inherit`, I used `$.extend(_this, args)`. (See jQuery's extend http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)

Comment: I am not using jquery because I am not using DOM, only canvas